# How to use nested ion-router-outlet in ionic6 vue?

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3

I have the following router setup:

```
{
name: "settings",
path: "/settings",
component: () => import("@/views/SettingsPage.vue"),
children: [
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: () => import("@/views/ProfileSettingsPage.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: () => import("@/views/AppSettingsPage.vue"),
  },
],
beforeEnter: authCheck,
},
```

My app.vue:

```
    <template>
      <ion-app>
        <ion-content ref="content" class="ion-padding" fullscreen="true">
        <ion-router-outlet id="main" class="mt-16" />
      </ion-content>
    </ion-app>
  </template>
```

I then want my children routes rendered in SettingsPage.vue:

```
    <template>
      <ion-page>
        Settings Page
        <!--Component to Navigate between Sub Settings-->
        <ion-router-outlet class="inner-router"></ion-router-outlet>
      </ion-page>
    </template>
```

The sub components gets shown but ionic styles makes them position absolute. I tried to change CSS with the applied "inner-router" class but ending up with more issues when it comes to scroll the ion-content in app.vue

Here is an example on what I want as a result:

```
    +------------------+                  +-----------------+
    | Settings         |                  | Settings        |
    | +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
    | | Profile      | |  +------------>  | | App         | |
    | | ...          | |                  | | ...         | |
    | +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
    +------------------+                  +-----------------+
```

Switching between the sub components Profile and App shouldn't reanimate the outer settings page which is why I tried to setup like this.

Thanks for any help!

The CSS i used:

```
<style lang="scss">
    .inner-router {
        inset: inherit;
        position: inherit;
        contain: inherit;
        overflow: inherit;
        z-index: inherit;
        --overflow: auto;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        flex: 1 1 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        contain: inherit;
        margin: auto !important;
        padding: auto !important;

    .ion-page {
        inset: inherit;
        position: inherit;
        contain: inherit;
        overflow: inherit;
        z-index: inherit;
    }
}
</style>
```

Apparently with my code only first page in that router-outlet seem to be animated correctly.